# Array destruct on callback input

Tags: javascript, destructor

I have an array with two elements. I wish to operate on them somehow, like the example below, but there should be somewhat elegant to destruct these two on a map callback.

```
const arr = [['You:',2], ['Me:',4]]

// Expected: [ 'You:2', 'Me:4' ]
// Output: [ 'undefinedundefined', 'undefinedundefined' ]
console.log(arr.map(({person, number}) => a+String(number)));
```

The code below works, but It requires indexation:

```
const arr = [['You:',2], ['Me:',4]]
let arg1, arg2;
 
// Output: [ 'You:2', 'Me:4' ]
console.log(
  arr.map(
    (args) => {
      arg1 = args[0];
      arg2 = args[1];
      return arg1+String(arg2)
     }
  )
);
```

Comment: You're trying to destructure an array as if it was an object, arrays don't have properties named person or number (the fact that those words don't appear in the definition should be a bit of a giveaway).

Comment: Is there some way to destruct it likewise?

Comment: "JavaScript destructure an array"

Comment: [a, b] = [10, 20];

Comment: In summary: the destructure syntax has to _mirror_ the structure you're destructuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply using the wrong syntax to destructure an array -

```js
arr.map(([person, number]) =>
  // ...
)
```